# Implement GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView with 2D Array? (Android Studio)

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

Currently I have a `2D` array of Objects, which I am trying to map onto a `RecyclerView` using `GridLayoutManager` with horizontal scroll. This is my code for the `onBindViewHolder`.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder vh, int index)
    {
        int row = index % myArray.getHeight();
        int col = index / myArray.getHeight();

        if (myArray[row][col].isValid())
        {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
        }
        else
        {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nocheck);
        }

    }
```

However this doesn't seem to work and crashes the app.

Comment: Describe how it doesn't work and how it crashes the app.

Comment: @Alan the grid does not properly represent the 2D Array. Say if at the 2D array at [2,0] it was Valid, on [2,0] of the GridView it was invalid. It crashes the app if I scroll too far to the right.